# Can the arithmetical hierarchy (AH) be defined in weaker (than PA) systems of arithmetic?

Tags: arithmetic, first-order-logic

such as Q, PRA, EFA, Presburger, or any others out there. I am a little confused here. They are all systems described in the language of first-order logic. The only differences among them are in the set of axioms. But in any of these arithmetical systems you have to express wff's using the same $\Sigma_k$ or $\Pi_k$ formulas. I also guess that the number of wff's in weaker systems is a subset of those that can be written in PA (because some things that can be defined in PA cannot in the weaker systems). Am I wrong? 
if I am correct up to here:are the subset of the AH that can be expressed in these weaker systems satisfied by the same subsets of N than those in PA (assuming the standard model of N)?

**Question1:** is the above correct?

**Question 2:** if so, is Post's theorem still valid for those subsets? or, is Post's theorem applicable to weaker systems of arithmetic? (at least the part that says that if the theory proves that a program C using a $\Sigma_{n−1}$-oracle halts, then C actually halts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I also guess that the number of wff's in weaker systems is a subset of those that can be written in PA".

The class of wffs of a theory is determined when we fix the *language* of the  theory. And Q (Robinson Arithmetic) and PA have the *same* language -- so Q and PA have the *same* class of wffs.

There are various ways of setting up versions of PRA. But usually the language for PRA is quantifier free (so in that respect its language is poorer than the language of PA), but PRA has a built-in function-expression for every primitive recursive function (so in that respect its language is infinitely richer than the language of PA). So the class of PRA wffs is neither contained in, nor contains, the class of PA wffs.

As for EFA, the class of wffs is a *superset* (not subset) of the wffs of PA (since the languages are the same, except that EFA also has the exponential built it). But because EFA only has restricted induction and PA can define the exponential by Gödel's trick but also has full induction, EFA is a weaker *theory*.

Comment: Ok, I got it wrong there. But let us limit to theories strong enough such that Gödel’s first incompleteness theorem do apply to them. Do you know if there is a generalized version of Post's theorem for them? and if not, do you know any reason why? (specifically, the part that says that if the theory proves that a program C using a Σn−1-oracle halts, then C actually halts), and that every Σn statement is equivalent to a halting statement?